# Why does my code make a new line

Tags: python

I'm tasked with taking some baseball team statistics from one txt file, finding the percent of games won, and outputting that to a separate file.

My code is as follows

```
infile = open("ALE.txt", "r")
outfile = open("ALE_sorted.txt", "w")

for line in infile:
    data = line.split(',')
    wins = eval(data[2])
    percentage = 162 / wins

    outfile.write(str(data[0]) + ", " + data[1] + ", " + data[2] + ", " + 
str(round(percentage, 3)) + "\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

The initial txt file looks like this in the format (teams, wins, losses):

Baltimore,93,69
Boston,69,93
New York,95,67
Tampa Bay,90,72
Toronto,73,89

And while my code correctly calculates the percentage of games won, it creates a line and I can't figure out why, looking exactly like this:

Baltimore, 93, 69
, 2.348
Boston, 69, 93
, 1.742
New York, 95, 67
, 2.418
Tampa Bay, 90, 72
, 2.25
Toronto, 73, 89, 1.82

It should only be 5 lines, not creating a new line right before the third comma every time. I've tried removing the "\n" but to no avail. Any tips?

Comment: because there is a `\n` inside `data[2]`, you can try `data[2].strip()`.

Comment: "**Solved thanks to the bros below" - You do not need to edit your question to note it is solved. Instead, pick an answer you think is best by clicking the green-outline checkmark next to it; this will tell Stack Overflow it is an Answered Question.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to say **Solved** in either the body or the title. If an answer you received solved the problem, the way to indicate so is by accepting the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark below the answer's score. You can also upvote that post at the same time if you feel it's appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing:

```
data = line.split(',')
```

to:

```
data = line.strip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

"line" is defined as "string of characters ending in line terminator". Thus, after you read the first line, `line` contains `"Baltimore,93,69\n"`. After split, `data` is `["Baltimore", "93", "69\n"]`. When you print out `data[2]`, there's a newline - because you never removed it.

Use `data = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')` to remove it. `rstrip` removes specified characters from the end of the string. `.rstrip()` would also work, but it removes any whitespace (such as trailing spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Your `data[2]` includes a newline. Just strip it away.